# Change footnote numbering format to a custom mapping

Tags: symbols, numbering, footnotes, book-design

My text contains some footnotes, and I want the footnote symbols in the text to be the English letters and the corresponding counterparts in the page footer to be Hindi numbers from 1 to 26, how may I achieve this behaviour in LaTeX? or more generally, for the footnote, how may I map some symbols in the text to some other symbols in the footer?

This is just an example of what I want:
[image]

In fact I want to map a *custom* set of symbols (not necessarily the English alphabet, it's just an example) to another set of symbols (like numbers from 1 to 26, for example!)

Comment: I believer \renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\alph{footnote}} will do the trick, but need an MWE to test it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main thing here seems to be the requirement to have multiple representations of the same footnote: `\arabic` in the text (say, the default), and `\alph` in the actual footnote (say).

You can change the default by adding

```
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\whatever{footnote}}
```

to the preamble (where you define `\whatever`).

Here's an implementation that uses the numbering mentioned in the first paragraph:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[paperheight=20\baselineskip]{geometry}% Just for this example

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\footnotetextnumbering}{\alph{footnote}}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\footnote}% <cmd>
  {\@footnotemark}% <search>
  {\protected@xdef\@thefntextmark{\footnotetextnumbering}%
   \@footnotemark}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\def\@makefntextmark{\hbox{\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefntextmark}}}
\patchcmd{\@makefntext}{\@makefnmark}{\@makefntextmark}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

One\footnote{First}. Two\footnote{Second}. Three\footnote{Third}. Four\footnote{Fourth}.
Five\footnote{Fifth}. Six\footnote{Sixth}. Seven\footnote{Seventh}. Eight\footnote{Eighth}.
Nine\footnote{Ninth}. Ten\footnote{Tenth}. Eleven\footnote{Eleventh}. Twelve\footnote{Twelfth}.
Thirteen\footnote{Thirteenth}. Fourteen\footnote{Fourteenth}. Fifteen\footnote{Fifteenth}. Sixteen\footnote{Sixteenth}.
Seventeen\footnote{Seventeenth}. Eighteen\footnote{Eighteenth}. Nineteen\footnote{Nineteenth}. Twenty\footnote{Twentieth}.
Twenty-one\footnote{Twenty-first}. Twenty-two\footnote{Twenty-second}. Twenty-three\footnote{Twenty-third}. Twenty-four\footnote{Twenty-fourth}.
Twenty-five\footnote{Twenty-fifth}. Twenty-six\footnote{Twenty-sixth}.

\end{document}
```